# Is there any difference between 'manuall'y opening and closing a log file and opening/closing it via a 'program'?

Tags: java, windows, file, logging, notepad

Here is how I can manually create a `log` file when using  windows.

- open notepad
- write `.LOG` in capital
- close the file

Next time when you open the file,automatically an entry of the current date/time will be added. Like :

```
.LOG
11:33 AM 07-Oct-12
```

and when you try to close the file,it asks you whether you want to save or not. If we click save , then next time say on `12:20 P.M 07-Oct-2012` we open that file,it will look like :

```
.LOG
11:33 AM 07-Oct-12

12:20 P.M 07-Oct-2012
```

and if we click don't save next time the file will look like :

```
.LOG
12:20 P.M 07-Oct-2012
```

The above is a manual way of storing logs. I am trying to do this using a program. I have already created a file named *LOG* and it has `.LOG` and a line break after it. But when I write an entry to this file such as `first entry` and then close the file/writer and then again open to write a new entry such as `second entry`,both get added one after another but not under separate time/date headings. Why is this ? Because if I open that particular file manually (not by a program) an entry of the current date and time gets added. Is there any difference between opening of file by a click and opening it via a `FileReader/FileWriter` ?

Here is how I have been attempting to write to a log file with each new entry under a separate date/time headings.

```
        try {
        File f = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/LOG.txt");
        if(f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("exists");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f,true);
            String content = jTextArea1.getText();
            writer.write(content);
            writer.close();

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
            int x;
            while( (x = reader.read() ) > 0) {
                System.out.print((char)x);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
```

The above snippet first writes an entry to the log file named *LOG.txt* and then attempts to read from that file. For example , initially the file looks like :

```
.LOG
```

After I add an entry , let it be *first log* it becomes :

```
.LOG
first log
```

when I expect it to look something like :

```
.LOG
12:20 P.M 07-Oct-2012
first entry..
12:23 P.M 07-Oct-2012
second entry..
12:28 P.M 07-Oct-2012
third entry..
```

But as I keep on adding new entries , it keeps on going like this :

```
.LOG
first entry..second entry..third entry...
```

When I go to the directory and open the file by double clicking it, an entry of date/time is added to the file and shown ,like this :

```
    .LOG
    first entry..second entry..third entry...
    12:20 P.M 07-Oct-2012
```

Why is that ? Is the instruction :

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileObject);
// read
reader.close();
```

is in't equal to opening and closing of file by first double clicking and then clicking on the cross and saving the file ?

*NOTE:* [~ Ref : How to use Notepad to create a Log file (Microsoft)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260563)

Comment: Simple reason is opening a file in windows is not same as _FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileObject);_

Comment: Wow - I never heard of that before :)  But it's a "notepad thing".  I don't think you can make much use of it from Java.  But it's certainly easy enough to write your *own* text file, and write your *own* timestamp into it.  Or use something like log4j...

Comment: This is a feature of `NotePad`, not built-in functionality of Windows. You need to do it yourself.